# Как узнать позицию RecyclerView и сохранить ее в переменную

Tags: java, recyclerview, android-shared-preferences

Задача в том, чтобы если закрыть приложение списка и позже снова открыть то список начинался не с начала а в том же месте где его закрыли.

В `onResume()` я получаю значение, например 3 и список прокручивается на третую позицию

```
SharedPreferences pref1;
final String IN = "index";
int idInt3;

@Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // получаю значение
        pref1 = getSharedPreferences(IN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // сохраняем значение в переменную
        int idInt3= pref1.getInt(IN, 0);
        // если есть значение в SharedPreferences
        if(pref1.contains(IN)) {
            // список прокручивается
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(idInt3);
        }
    }
```

Здесь все понятно, но как получить номер позиции и сохранить в переменную?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    // получить номер позиции списка
    int index = ???
    //// сохраняем номер позиции в index
    pref1 = getSharedPreferences(IN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref1.edit();
    ed.putBoolean(IN, index);
    ed.apply();

    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы пробовали методы типа findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); findLastVisibleItemPosition();  ?
Вот тут похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237082/how-to-get-recyclerview-position-for-scrolling?rq=1 думаю поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, я пока немного другим способом воспользовался, карявым, но вроде более менее рабочим. Но этим тоже надо попробовать.